# What is the performance impact of searching with md5 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to obfuscate my ids in my clients by having them hold hashed (md5) values for resources in my db and then finding them using

```
 select * from resources where md5(_id) = "3c164361es869624aa2c16cdd034abaa";
```

but I don't understand the inner workings of mysql and this seems to me like something that may hinder performance.

Comment: Indexes can't be used if you perform a function on the column

Answer (score 0):

Since _id is a constant and wont change, recalculating its md5 everytime is a waste of CPU time & memory, additionally as the table will grow big you will see increased latency.

You would be better off with an additional column for md5_id of your _id column, whenever you insert a new row just calculate its md5 and save it in the new md5_id column, this way you just do md5 once and not on every query.

your new query should look like

```
select * from resources where md5_id = "3c164361es869624aa2c16cdd034abaa";
```